# 3 different Insert into #table select in parallel SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, parallel-processing

I have `1 temporary table` and I am doing something like:

```
Insert into #table1 select ...  from #temporal
Insert into #table2 select ...  from #temporal
Insert into #table3 select ...  from #temporal
```

As every select take a considerable time I would like to paralelize these 3 queries is there any way to do this in `SQL Server 2008`?

Comment: Why are you putting the same data set into these tables? could you not just use #temporal in the rest of your code? You can index #temporal and it might go faster.

Comment: I need 3 temporal tables, Their results are different (3 tables with different fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the root of the problem is that the `SELECT from #temporal` is a performance problem. Do you have an index on that temp table `#temporal`? Likely an index (or statistics update) would help you out to avoid writing more code to work around this problem.

Are you able, or have you tried measuring performance against storing the results from that one `#temporal` SELECT into a table variable?

```
DECLARE @myTemporal TABLE (id int, foo varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @myTemporal (id, foo)
    SELECT id, foo FROM #temporal;
```

Then your *n* INSERTs can pull from the table variable, rather than the expensive/nonperformant query.

```
Insert into #table1 select id, foo from @myTemporal;
Insert into #table2 select id, foo from @myTemporal;
Insert into #table3 select id, foo from @myTemporal;
```

The benefit is that you won't have to execute the SELECT 3x against your temp table. You'd be inserting into your 3 temp tables from the table variable. All rows, no WHERE clause.

Comment: Well, the reason is because I need 3 temporal tables, they will be used for other storeprocedure...

Comment: @dark: It's clear you need the 3 temp tables. I'm suggesting you load them up via a table variable if its performance is suitable for your environment.

Comment: so is it better to use @tablevar  than #tempTable?? Why?

Comment: Use a table variable when you don't need permanent storage. In this case I've suggested you use it instead of hitting `#temporal` 3x.